# Git push folder but not the content?

Tags: git

Currently I've used git

I have this directory `public/images/facility` where all facility images are being stored.

What I want to do is, I want to push the project on new repo this directory `public/images/facility`

but not the images currently it contains.

How can I rule it on my `gitignore` file?

Because this directory contains huge amounts of images, But still I want my repo to recognize this dir `public/images/facility`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git` does not store empty folders, so you need to store *some* file.

In your case, you can place a `.gitignore` file in this folder, with content :

```
# ignore all files except .gitignore :
*
!.gitignore
```

---

In some repos, you will see folders containing an empty file, by convention it is usually called `.gitkeep`

Comment: This is what I would do. Note: The `.gitkeep` convention is intended to put in place a folder structure that later will have files in them. At which point, the `.gitkeep` file should be deleted.